# Intent for opening folders

Tags: android, android-intent

not sure why whenever i call the default file manager via intent, there is a "Package Installer" in the list, selecting it would popup and error "There is a problem parsing the package".

screenshot:

[image]

im using this code btw

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://" + mRecorder.getRecordDir()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: There is no default file manager on most android devices as they come from the manufacturer, though either the end user or a particular manufacturer can add one.   If the user has something like OpenIntents file manager installed, then you can use the relevant docs for that (it was specifically intended to take both one-way intents and to pick files for use by a requesting app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no action on your `Intent`. If you are going to use implicit `Intents`, please provide an action.

> whenever i call the default file manager via intent

First, there is no "default file manager" in Android, as Mr. Stratton points out in his comment.

Second, I have no idea why you think that `Intent` would bring up a "default file manager" in any case.

Comment: how is the proper way of opening a folder using intent?

Comment: @Joe: There is no "proper way of opening a folder using intent", unless you are going to have the user install some third-party app for this (e.g., OpenIntents, as Mr. Stratton points out in his comment). Android, like iOS, tries to get rid of the concept of "folders" as much as possible.

Comment: yes, i know that you need a third-party app to do that. how would you call those apps?

Comment: @Joe: That would be a fine question for the author of the app in question. I would hope that they would use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or possibly `ACTION_PICK`, but that is up to them.